# Do I need a transit visa at Shenzhen as a Filipino citizen?

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, shenzhen

I will be flying from Christchurch, New Zealand to the Philippines. There is an 8 hour stopover at SZX airport. I am a Philippine passport holder. Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 5):

You won't need a visa as long as you stay in the transit area of the airport as detailed by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the database used by airport staff:

> Transiting without a visa is possible for: Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit
>   area of the airport and have documents required for the next
>   destination.

If you need/want to leave the transit area you are able to get an entry permit on arrival:

> Passengers with a confirmed onward air, cruise or train ticket to a
>   third country within 24 hours can obtain an entry permit on arrival.
>   They must have documents required for the next destination.